# What reparametrization of vector parameters makes the Jeffreys prior correspond to the uniform prior?

Tags: jeffreys-prior, matrix-calculus

What reparametrization of vector of parameters $\theta$ makes the Jeffreys prior
$$\sqrt{\det I(\theta)}$$
correspond to the uniform prior?

A change of parametrization from $\theta$ to $\eta$ changes the Fisher information as follows (I think):

\begin{align}
  I(\eta)
  &= (\nabla_{\eta}{\theta})
  I(\theta \mid X)
  {(\nabla_{\eta}{\theta})}^T
\end{align}

E.g., for a Bernoulli distribution parametrized by probability $p\in[0,1]$, the Jeffreys prior is proportional to $\sqrt{\frac1{p(1-p)}}$.  I believe the transformation in this case of

$$\eta = \int \sqrt{\frac1{p(1-p)}}\, dp = 2\arcsin(\sqrt{p})$$

has a uniform Jeffreys prior?

How do I generalize this to vector-valued values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [Variance-stabilizing transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation).

Comment: This appears to be a related concept, can you provide any literature authoritatively establishing a connection between the two?